# Condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `Mix`:

```
     Name  Surname   Date   Status
0      A     A8       1902    aab
1      B     B9       1976    ab
2      C     C8       1901    aab
3      D     D4       1986    abc
4      E     E7       1986    abb
5      F     F1       1986    ab
6      G     G5       1987    abc
7      H     H2       1998    acc
```

I need to create a new dataframe according to several conditions:
1) Take all the dublicates from column `Status` and get this:

```
          Name  Surname   Date   Status
    0      A     A8       1902    aab
    1      B     B9       1976    ab
    2      C     C8       1901    aab
    3      D     D4       1986    abc
    5      F     F1       1986    ab
    6      G     G5       1987    abc
```

2) Take only those rows of same Status, whose Date differs from each other more or less than 1 and get this:

```
          Name  Surname   Date   Status
    0      A     A8       1902    aab
    2      C     C8       1901    aab
    3      D     D4       1986    abc
    6      G     G5       1987    abc
```

can anybody help?

Comment: can you show what you've tried, for example for 1) look at `duplicated`, for 2) look at `groupby`

Comment: yep i did both, but dublicated gave me only the list of values which are dublicated, not the dataframe as i need. Particulary, i tried Mix.set_index('Status).index.get_duplicates()

Comment: You need to use the list of values that are duplicated to filter the df, can you have a go and if you're still stuck come back with your attempts. SO is not a code writing service, if we just give you the answer it doesn't necessarily help you learn how to solve similar problems later IMO

Comment: okay, it makes sense

Comment: @EdChum i filtered it so step one is done, thanks) What about step two, can you give me the direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the result of `duplicated` to filter the main df using `isin`:

```
In [38]:
duplicated = df[df['Status'].isin(df.loc[df['Status'].duplicated(), 'Status'])]
duplicated

Out[38]:
  Name Surname  Date Status
0    A      A8  1902    aab
1    B      B9  1976     ab
2    C      C8  1901    aab
3    D      D4  1986    abc
5    F      F1  1986     ab
6    G      G5  1987    abc
```

Then you want to `groupby` on the Status column and call `diff` on the 'Date' column and filter by comparing whether the difference is <= 1:

```
In [44]:
duplicated[duplicated.groupby('Status')['Date'].diff() <= 1]

Out[44]:
  Name Surname  Date Status
2    C      C8  1901    aab
6    G      G5  1987    abc
```

you can then get the list of 'Status' ids that meet this criteria and filter:

```
In [45]:
final_statuses = duplicated[duplicated.groupby('Status')['Date'].diff() <= 1]['Status']
final_statuses

Out[45]:
2    aab
6    abc
Name: Status, dtype: object

In [46]:
duplicated.loc[duplicated['Status'].isin(final_statuses)]

Out[46]:
  Name Surname  Date Status
0    A      A8  1902    aab
2    C      C8  1901    aab
3    D      D4  1986    abc
6    G      G5  1987    abc
```